# How to inject several beans with Spring Java config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Given spring java-config with method that returns list of beans:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "resultConsumers")
    public List<Consumer> getConsumers() {
        return Arrays.asList(...);
    }
}
```

How can I inject it in another bean?

```
class Bean {

   @Inject
   what?
}
```

P.S. It is not list with different implementations of consumers, they are all instances of the same class.

Comment: You want to inject the bean with name `resultConsumers` into the bean of type `Bean`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i want to have that list inside a bean, no matter how

Answer (score 2):

When you annotate a `Collection` type with `@Autowired`, Spring doesn't look for a corresponding bean of that type. Instead it looks for the component type that the `Collection` is meant to store.

Instead, use `@Resource` with the bean name.

```
@Resource(name ="resultConsumers")
private List<Consumer> consumers;
```

Comment: @AdamSkywalker If you have many `Consumer` beans (as opposed to a bean of type `List<Consumer>`), you might need to indicate the bean by name.

Comment: why you answered then?

Comment: now I need time to check it, won't try it in production)

Answer (score -1):

You should not create the @Bean as a list.  Simply add all of your Consumer objects as individual beans.  Autowire a field as a List of Consumers, and Spring will find all of your Consumer beans and create the List for you...

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Consumer consumer1() {
        return new Consumer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer consumer2() {
        return new Consumer();
    }
}
...
class Bean {

    //  Contains consumer1 and consumer2
    @Inject
    private List<Consumer> consumers;
 }
```

Comment: No, but it still works even if the implementations are the same

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public List<Consumer> getConsumers() {
        return Arrays.asList(...);
    }
}
```

And the injection is like this

```
    class InjectionPoint{

   @Autowred
   private Consumer [] consumerList;
}
```

And that's all.